# ClassNotFoundExeption when embedding applet in webpage

Tags: java, applet, html, classnotfoundexception

I made a java applet in eclipse and I am trying to embed it in a webpage. I exported the jar file, and my html looks like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Title </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <applet code ="Game.class" archive="applet.jar" width = "854" height="641">

    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting a class not found exception for Game.class.
I used 7 zip to check that Game.class exists and it does. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a package declaration in your `Game` class?

Comment: what is the directory location of game.class and html page u have ??

Comment: I declare my package at the top of Game:  package edu.elon.game;

Comment: The directory of game.class is: C:\Users\Chad\Desktop\Allergic to Snakes\applet.jar\edu\elon\game\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I declare my package at the top of Game: package edu.elon.game;

Then you need to specify this in the applet tag `code` tag to match the fully qualified class name

```
<applet code ="edu.elon.game.Game.class" archive="applet.jar" width = "854" height="641">
               ^-----------^
```

Comment: Thank you very much Reimeus! I really appreciate it.

Comment: *"..to match the fully qualified class name"*  Which is `edu.elon.game.Game` (correct) as opposed to `edu.elon.game.Game.class` (tolerated, but not correct).

Comment: @AndrewThompson How is it not correct? The `.class` extension is shown in the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/appletviewertags.html) :)

Comment: Yes, it is peppered throughout the docs.  But the value is *supposed* to be the FQN.  That page also states *"The object tag is the HTML 4.0 tag for embedding applets"*  There is no such thing as a 'tag' in HTML.  They are HTML *elements*.  And that is intended to show just how much we should trust Sun or Oracle on writing HTML in general.  ;)  I could expand on this if you were to ask a specific question about it.